# Simple Python Excel password crack - Brute Force

Tags: python, excel, passwords

For a demonstration I want to crack an excel file (named 'xl') password. I use the following code but (1) it fails to open excel and (2) it does not stop running when the password is cracked.

```
import itertools
import string 
from win32com.client import Dispatch

file = input('Path: ')

chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits

for password_length in range(1, 2):
    for password in itertools.product(chars, repeat=password_length):
        password = ''.join(password)

        print ('Testing password: '+ password)
        instance = Dispatch ('Excel.Application')

        try:
            instance.Workbooks.Open(file, False, True, None, password)
            print ('Password Cracked: ' + password)
            #break

        except:
            pass
```

I set the excel password as 'p' and the code just runs through 1 character combinations for simplicity. Moreover, when you run the code it requires as input the path of the excel file.

I can't figure out my mistake and I would appreciate some help. Also if doing this for a word document is easier please let me know.

Comment: The `break` line in the `try:` block is commented out so it doesn't get executed when the password is cracked and will just keep executing the for loop

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I commented the line because when it runs the program with break command it stops in the first iteration.

Comment: In that case it seems that `instance.Workbooks.Open()` does not throw an error if it can't open the workbook. You might want to store the result of the `instance.Workbooks.Open()` and check if it is `None`, instead of having a `try/catch`

Comment: When I run `instance.Workbooks.Open(file)` I get `<COMObject Open>`

Answer (score 0):

Loop does not stop because you have **#break** commented out.