# unprotect excel workbook with python when password is lost

Tags: python, excel, passwords

I have some protected excel files (about 5000 files) that their password is lost.
How can I unprotect them using python? Is there a way to unprotect them all at once?

Comment: You can't, If you could that would be a terrible security feature.

Comment: So who did not keep a secure copy of the passwords? Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54544746/4961700 but other posts also exist.

Comment: What format are the excel files? What year were these last saved? What do you mean by protected, exactly? Do you need to enter a password to open the file, or do you just need a password to unlock particular sheets within the workbook?